# REST Jersey HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I tries looking on stackoverflow to solve this issue, but I can't find anything. Code seems to be OK, but I get a HTTP 404. Could you help me, please?

```
package rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import domain.Employee;

@Path("/employees")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @GET  
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)    
    public Response getAllEmployees(){

      List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      employees.add(new Employee("Keith", "Brown", "Official", 27000));
      employees.add(new Employee("Jenny", "Pitman", "Trainer", 31000));
      String output =  employees.toString();

      return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }
}
```

and the web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>VPP JavaEE 18 Rest DWP eu</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- configuration for jax rs -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>rest</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I go the browser and write:

```
http://localhost:8080/VPP JavaEE 18 Rest DWP eu/webservice/employees
```

But I get A HTTP 404 The requested resource is not available with no clues.

However, Tomcat REST servlet IS working, because if I write:

```
http://localhost:8080/VPP JavaEE 18 Rest DWP eu/blablalba
```

I receive a different message:

HTTP Status 404 - /project-name/blablalba

I must also mention that it works if I write:

```
http://localhost:8080/VPP JavaEE 18 Rest DWP eu/index.html
```

Comment: It would be display-name in place of project-name. Can you try and see?

Comment: If display-name is my.project, URL would be http://localhost:8080/my.project/webservice/employees

Comment: Actually, the project name is different

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy is right, you don't give the display name in the url, you need to give the project name. the example you gave with /project-name/blablalba should be /project-name/webserice/blablalba